# Apple Push Notifications are not working in production

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

With my app on the App Store, push notifications are not working.
With my app in Development, push notifications are working.

I guess I should have tested via an Ad Hoc deployment. Anyway, here is what I know...

**App ID**

my App ID is com.MyName.My-App

It has Push Notifications enabled for Development and Distribution

[image]

**APNs Certificates**

I have both Development and Distribution certificates. It's the Dist I care about.

[image]

It has the name com.MyName.My-App

**Exporting to a PEM**

I've selected both the Cert and private key, and exported it, as follows:

[image]

and password protected it.

I then ran

```
openssl pkcs12 -in Certificates.p12 -out pushcert.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

supplying the password, and successfully getting the `pushcert.pem` output.

**Downloading App**

I cleared by server side device token for my device, I download my app from the app store, opened it and accepted Push Notifications, and then logged into my server to check my device token. I have my production device token now. I ran this simple php script (which works when I supply my development device token) but fails with my production device token.

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'myProductionDeviceTokenInHere';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'myPasswordIsInHere';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Test';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'pushcert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', 'entrust_2048_ca.cer');

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Why is it failing? It works with my development device token, but not my production device token. Have I not done something correctly?

Comment: you try build adhoc with current certificates for push notification? Maybe your add on store use difference certificate.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that you likely are distributing with the wrong provisioning profile. 
In order to receive Push Notifications in the final release, you need to have the newest provisioning profile installed in which you have already enabled Push Notifications for distribution. This is the most common mistake and I encountered it once or twice in the past.

So now you have to take the following steps:

- Log in to the Apple Developer Center
- Create a new Provisioning Profile for this App id for distribution
  [image: Screenshot]
- Continue to set it up fully, by entering all the necessary details
- Download the profile and double-click it to install it
- In your project under `Build Settings-> Code Signing -> Distribution` select your newly created profile
- Now Push Notifications will reach the end user also in the Distribution builds.

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: I created a new Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile instead of a App Store profile, to test if that would work first... before I create the Distribution one, push it to the App Store, and wait 2 weeks. This way I can test if the Ad Hoc works right away. Anyway, it did not :@. This issue is killing me!

Comment: So you made a Ad Hoc one, installed it in Xcode and it didn't work?

Comment: Yup. I'm killing everything in my member center right now. Cleaning it all out. Going to record my screen via QuickTime and set everything up, and see if it fails again. Then at least this way I'll have all my steps recorded.

Comment: This is really weird. Did you consider using a third party service like parse?

Comment: And if not, try to make a dummy project and then check this with the provisioning profile and parse. If this works it's something with your Push Server. If it doesn't it's Apple's bug and you can open a technical support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the sandbox cert on the server! you have to change this in order for it to work from sandbox to prod.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a problem with the third party Ruby Gem I was using (rpush). Not exactly sure what, but as soon as I switched it out, everything has been great.